# sums and percents from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data with columns for q1,q2,q3

so the data may look like

```
q1    q2    q3
1     1     2
1     2     1
2     3     1
```

so there is one record for each submission from a user, and theis one record contains the answer to question 1,2 and 3...which is probably not the best table design for what I want to do!
I would like to get get counts and percents from each question

so the results set would look like

```
questionNum     responseNum   count   percent
1               1             2       66
1               2             1       33
2               1             1       33
2               2             1       33
2               3             1       33
3               1             2       66
3               2             1       33
```

Is this possible to do in 1 query or would this need to be 3 separate queries?

Comment: Explain your question in detail with what type of source data and how you want to genrate your output with example.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this query returns what you want if not than explain your question further. 
Try this:

```
SELECT questionNum, responseNum, `count`,
       FLOOR(`count` * 100 / (SELECT SUM(`count`) FROM question WHERE questionNum = b\q.questionNum)) percent
FROM question q
```